# System.IO.Compression.GZipStream vs IIS gZip

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, compression, gzip

Our web applications have been using GZipStream for a long time to compress response data.  I see that IIS can do this compression for the application instead and provide some settings for load/performance.  When I compare the content size of the same page I see that the IIS gZip is always not compressed as much as compared to GZipStream in the application code.  I tried configuring the Compression Level for IIS at different settings but always get the same size.

Why would using gzip in the application result in a smaller page size?  Is the gZip used by IIS not as effective as using GZipStream?  Is there some additional configuration for getting the Compression Level to work other than setting it in the config?

Comment: Also, using gzipstream, you can save some content or static files in gzip as cached files or content.
More than 70% browsers supports gzip, so in more than 70% request you can return gzip responce and extract gziped files or content (gzipped cache) for 30% another requests.
So you will have two beneffits vs IIS gzip:
1) using cache
2) gziped cache